# Como extrair todo enésimo elemento de uma lista?

Tags: r, lista

Considerando uma lista composta por diversos vetores:

```
lista<-list(c("1949", "1963", "45", "X2752009", "X2752013", "X2753007", "X2850009", "X2851005", "X2851008", "X2851014", "X2852002", "X2852003", "X2852011", "X2852016", "X2852020", "X2853005", "X2853006", "X2853008","X2854003", "X2854007", "X2854011", "X2950003", "X2950007", "X2950008", "X2950010", "X2950011", "X2950014", "X2950017", "X2950018", "X2950020", "X2950024", "X2950029", "X2950030", "X2950033", "X2950035", "X2950041", "X2951003", "X2951022", "X2951043", "X2952002", "X2952006", "X2954001", "X2956007", "X3051003", "X3051013", "X3052009", "X3053007", "X3053012"), c("1950", "1964", "49", "X2751008", "X2752009", "X2752013", "X2753007", "X2850009", "X2851005", "X2851008", "X2851014", "X2852002", "X2852003", "X2852011", "X2852016", "X2852020", "X2853005", "X2853006", "X2853008", "X2854003", "X2854007", "X2854011", "X2950003", "X2950007", "X2950008", "X2950010", "X2950011", "X2950014", "X2950017", "X2950018", "X2950020", "X2950024", "X2950029", "X2950030", "X2950033", "X2950035", "X2950041", "X2951003", "X2951022", "X2951043", "X2952002", "X2952006","X2952012", "X2952029", "X2954001", "X2956007", "X3051003", "X3051013", "X3052007", "X3052009", "X3053007", "X3053012"), c("1951", "1965", "50", "X2751008", "X2752009", "X2752013", "X2753007", "X2850009", "X2851005", "X2851008", "X2851014", "X2852002", "X2852003", "X2852011", "X2852012", "X2852014", "X2852016", "X2852020", "X2853005", "X2853006", "X2853008", "X2854003", "X2854007", "X2854011", "X2950003", "X2950007", "X2950008", "X2950010", "X2950011", "X2950014", "X2950017", "X2950018", "X2950020", "X2950024", "X2950030", "X2950033", "X2950035", "X2950041", "X2951003", "X2951022", "X2952002", "X2952012", "X2952029", "X2954001", "X2956007", "X3051003", "X3051013", "X3052003", "X3052007", "X3052009", "X3053003", "X3053007", "X3053012"), c("1952", "1966", "57", "X2751008", "X2752009", "X2752013", "X2753007", "X2850007", "X2850009", "X2851001", "X2851005", "X2851008", "X2851014", "X2851033", "X2851037", "X2852002", "X2852003", "X2852011", "X2852012", "X2852014", "X2852016", "X2852020", "X2853005", "X2853006", "X2853008", "X2854003", "X2854007", "X2854011", "X2950003", "X2950007", "X2950008", "X2950010", "X2950011", "X2950014", "X2950017", "X2950018", "X2950020", "X2950024", "X2950030", "X2950033", "X2950035", "X2950041", "X2951003", "X2951022", "X2952002", "X2952012", "X2952029", "X2953016", "X2954001", "X2956007", "X3051003","X3051013", "X3052003", "X3052007", "X3052009", "X3053005", "X3053007", "X3053012", "X3150001", "X3154001"), c("1953", "1967", "58", "X2751008", "X2752009", "X2752013", "X2753007", "X2850007", "X2850009", "X2851001", "X2851005", "X2851008", "X2851014", "X2851018", "X2851026", "X2851033", "X2852002", "X2852003", "X2852011", "X2852012", "X2852014", "X2852016", "X2852017", "X2852020", "X2853005", "X2853006", "X2853008", "X2854003", "X2854007", "X2854011", "X2950003", "X2950007", "X2950008", "X2950009", "X2950010", "X2950011", "X2950014", "X2950017", "X2950018", "X2950020", "X2950024", "X2950030", "X2950033", "X2950035", "X2950041", "X2951022", "X2952012", "X2952029", "X2953016", "X2954001", "X2956007", "X3051003", "X3052002", "X3052003", "X3052007", "X3052009", "X3053005", "X3053007", "X3053012", "X3150001", "X3154001"), c("1954", "1968", "55", "X2751008", "X2752009", "X2752013", "X2753007", "X2850007", "X2850009", "X2851001", "X2851005", "X2851008", "X2851014", "X2851018", "X2851026", "X2851033", "X2852002", "X2852003", "X2852011", "X2852014", "X2852016", "X2852017", "X2852020", "X2853006", "X2853008", "X2854003", "X2854011", "X2950003", "X2950007", "X2950008", "X2950009", "X2950010", "X2950011", "X2950014", "X2950017", "X2950018", "X2950020", "X2950024", "X2950030", "X2950033", "X2950035", "X2950041", "X2951022", "X2952029", "X2953016", "X2954001", "X2956007", "X3051003", "X3052002", "X3052003", "X3052007", "X3052008", "X3052009", "X3053005", "X3053007", "X3053012", "X3150001", "X3154001"))
```

Trata-se de um resultado de um teste, do qual, preciso analisar o terceiro elemento de todos vetores desta lista. Para facilitar o entendimento vou chama-los de valores ALFA.

Tentei acessa-los por meio dos operadores `[]` e `[[]]`, mas obtive a seguinte mensagem de erro ao aplicar a função abaixo:

```
lista[[1:6]][3]
Error in lista[[1:6]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

As análises que preciso realizar são simples, uma delas é saber em qual a posição do valor máximo entre os valores de ALFA (Pensei na função `which.max()`).

As demais análises são seguem o mesmo nível e serão possíveis apenas com a manipulação da solução deste caso.

Comment: Só pra explicar porque sua tentativa não deu certo: O operador `[[` só pode ser utilizado para retornar um elemento do objeto, porque ele retorna um objeto do mesmo tipo do elemento (vetor, no seu caso), enquanto o operador `[` sempre retorna um objeto do mesmo tipo do objeto no qual é aplicado, mesmo que ele tenha apenas um elemento. Isso pode ser um pouco confuso, mas você verá a diferença se comparar os resultados de `lista[[1]]` e `lista[1]` usando as funções `str`, `class` e `typeof`.

Comment: Obrigado pelas explicações @Molx! Muito uteis e relevantes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar `base` p/ obter o terceiro elemento de cada vetor:

```
> sapply(lista, function(x) x[3])
[1] "45" "49" "50" "57" "58" "55"
```

A mesma coisa você pode faze usando o pacote `purrr` com a sintaxe um pouco mais concisa:

```
library(purrr)
> map_chr(lista, ~.x[3])
[1] "45" "49" "50" "57" "58" "55"
```

P/ descobrir o índice da lista que possui o maior `alfa`, vc pode usar a função `detect_index` ainda do pacote `purrr`:

```
> alfa <- map_chr(lista, ~.x[3])
> detect_index(lista, ~.x[3] == max(alfa))
```

Ou ainda pegar o vetor inteiro em que se encontra o maior valor de `alfa`:

```
> keep(lista, ~.x[3] == max(alfa))
[[1]]
 [1] "1953"     "1967"     "58"       "X2751008" "X2752009" "X2752013" "X2753007"
 [8] "X2850007" "X2850009" "X2851001" "X2851005" "X2851008" "X2851014" "X2851018"
[15] "X2851026" "X2851033" "X2852002" "X2852003" "X2852011" "X2852012" "X2852014"
[22] "X2852016" "X2852017" "X2852020" "X2853005" "X2853006" "X2853008" "X2854003"
[29] "X2854007" "X2854011" "X2950003" "X2950007" "X2950008" "X2950009" "X2950010"
[36] "X2950011" "X2950014" "X2950017" "X2950018" "X2950020" "X2950024" "X2950030"
[43] "X2950033" "X2950035" "X2950041" "X2951022" "X2952012" "X2952029" "X2953016"
[50] "X2954001" "X2956007" "X3051003" "X3052002" "X3052003" "X3052007" "X3052009"
[57] "X3053005" "X3053007" "X3053012" "X3150001" "X3154001"
```

Comment: Obrigado Daniel. Com isto já evito um laço. Já estava satisfeito com primeira versão, mas com a edição ficou melhor. Valeu!

Comment: Só tome cuidado que o resultado é um vetor de caracteres e se vc tiver por ex. nº 100 e 11, o R vai considerar 100 < 11. Talvez seja necessário converter p/ numérico antes

Comment: Entendido! Vou fazer a conversão.

Comment: @Jean Se quiser simplificar ainda mais a primeira opção, pode evitar a declaração da função e usar o seguinte: `sapply(lista, "[", 3)`